# Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook - border for merged cells

Tags: apache-poi

I use SXSSFWorkbook() to create my workbook. I have a requirement to merge a few cells across rows/columns and also give it a border.

My problem is: merging of cells with out applying a border works perfectly fine, However, the moment I try to merge the cells and apply border application runs into an Exception.

```
ERROR view - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[2] in the range [0,204] that is already written to disk.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[2] in the range [0,204] that is already written to disk.
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:113)
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil.getRow(CellUtil.java:90)
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.RegionUtil.setRightBorderColor(RegionUtil.java:139)
```

My Code:

```
CellRangeAddress rangeAdd = new CellRangeAddress(2, 41, 0, 0);
sheet.addMergedRegion(rangeAdd);
RegionUtil.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex(), rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
RegionUtil.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex(), rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
RegionUtil.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex(), rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
RegionUtil.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex(), rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);

RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN, rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN, rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
RegionUtil.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN, rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
RegionUtil.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN, rangeAdd, sheet, mWb);
```

Any help/pointers around this would be great.

Comment: When are you trying to add the merged region? Just after creating those rows, or at the very end?

Comment: Regardless of where I create I get the same issue. I tried 2 approached: 1) Merge and apply border to the region as and when the demand for it arises. 2) Keep track of all the merge needed. Do it at the end. In both the approaches the merge works fine with out having border. But, the moment I introduce the code to apply border, application crashes.

Comment: SXSSF works by only keeping a few rows in memory (you can configure how many). Any operation that uses rows no longer in memory will fail. So, what happens if you try to create a merged region of just a few rows, where those rows are still in memory?

Comment: How many rows do I merge is not configurable nor it is static number, that is my problem. Number of rows to merge could vary - could be as low as 2 or could be any number > 2.

Comment: Increase the SXSSF window size to always be > the number of rows you want to merge, and you ought to be fine then!